# Is it safe to stop Product Prices indexing?

Tags: magento-1.7, indexing

To work filter fine, I will have to stop **indexing of Product Prices**.

Can anyone tell me whether it is safe or not?

What problem will I have to face?

Comment: Everything about this suggests a deeper issue, indexers should be part of your solution and not a hurdle to overcome in magento.

Comment: @LukeRodgers For filter, min_price from catalog_product_index_price table is used. The value in min_price inserted or after indexing is not the right one. Only solution I find is to force to put the correct value and stop indexing for prices.

Comment: Surely the error in that case is that min_price is being incorrectly indexed? Have you got a catalog rule that is changing it perhaps?

Comment: @LukeRodgers - Catalog rule works fine but in my selling price we also give discount on making charge because of which min_price value is not what I am expecting.

Comment: @LukeRodgers - No i did not get a catalog rule